# Why can I only see my CouchDB view from _utils?

Tags: view, couchdb, couchapp

I'm following [IBM's tutorial on CouchDB](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-couchapp/section4.html) and ran into a problem viewing my docs. When I visit http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/database.html?contacts/_design/contacts/_view/byname#, I can see my docs in the view just fine.

[image]

However, when I visit http://127.0.0.1:5984/contacts/_design/contacts/_view/byname (and subsequently try to view the same data in my app via `db.view("contacts/byname", {...`), I only see `null` results for my key/value pairs.

[image]

I don't think it's a security issue; I'm able to see the view in *_utils* whether I'm logged in or not.

**EDIT**

Here is the source code for my view:

```
function(doc) {
   if (doc.name) {
      emit(doc.name, doc);
   }
}
```

**Why can I see it in one place but not the other?**

Comment: What does your view source code look like?

Comment: I've updated the question with my source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Antonios, the command

```
couchapp generate view contacts byname
```

has created a file `views/byname/reduce.js` with an empty reduce function. You should remove it or query with `?reduce=false` (Futon adds it by default.)

As a side note: while using Futon, you can use Firebug to see the queries that are being done.

Comment: Is there a way to do so in Chrome also, or should I use Firebug Lite in Chrome?

Comment: @Wraith, on Chrome press F12 and select the Network tab (but Firebug is prettier ;-)).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you have a reduce function that discards the document contents, or reduces to null? I see from your screenshot that you haven't clicked the "Reduce" checkbox, thus what you see is results just from the map function.

Comment: +1 for getting me on the right track. That's a fantastic tip, thank you!